# PHP E-Commerce Experiences

Tags: php, e-commerce

I might be tasked to make an e-commerce site.

I can make it in Magento, osCMax, basically any PHP based prepackaged system.

Here's the three main features.

My boss is the admin.

My boss' friends can register.

My boss' friends can sell stuff.

My boss gets a cut.

Anybody got suggestions about what to use? Stories can help too.

Comment: I think you left out the three main features.

Comment: Just make sure that people can't order decimal or negative quantities. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are the three main features but consider also http://www.prestashop.com/. It's easy to learn, excellent community and features.

Answer (score 0):

osCMax i have not heard of or used,

Magento is by far the most advanced and complete solution the only problem with it, is its XML Based the best bet is to look at a comparison site of the systems

http://www.hotscripts.com/category/php/scripts-programs/e-commerce/